# Limits and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty )$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$.

If $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = c$, show that $c = 0$.

I know that since $f$ is differentiable, then it is also continuous on $(0,\infty)$. I also know that, by definition of limits, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $M$ such that whenever $x>M$, $|f(x)-1|<\epsilon$.

Any hints on how to start/which theorems to use would be very helpful!

Comment: Suppose $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = c \neq 0$. Show that $f$ cannot be bounded on $[K,\infty)$ for any $K > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \lim\limits_{x \to h} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}  $

f and f' are continuous so we can switch the limits order :

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to h} \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim\limits_{x \to h}\frac{1-1}{h} =0 $$

Comment: Can you explain in detail why $f$ being continuous entitles a change in the order of limits?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I don't think you can do that.. After extensive googling of properties of limits this doesn't seem to appear anywhere

Comment: @PineappleTacos Acording to baby rudin page 144 , F is continious if and only if  
$ \lim\limits_{t \to x} \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f_n(t)= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \lim\limits_{t\to x} f_n(t)$

Answer (score 2):

By Mean Value Theorem, there exist a sequence $ \{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$, $n<a_n<n+1$, such that $f^\prime (a_n) = \frac{f(n+1)-f(n)}{(n+1)-n}=f(n+1)-f(n)$. Take limits on both sides and use continuity

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:** (i) Given $\epsilon \gt 0$, $|f(x)-1|\lt \epsilon/2$ for large enough $x$. (ii) By the Mean Value Theorem, for any $x$, we have $f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(c_x)$ for some $c_x$ between $x$ and $x+1$. (iii) So for large enough $x$, there is a $c_x\gt x$ such that $|f'(c_x)|\lt \epsilon$. (iv) Since the limit of $f'(x)$ by assumption **exists**, it must be $0$.

**Remark:**
Note that the existence of the limit of $f'(x)$ is an essential assumption. It is not hard to find differentiable $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=1$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ does not exist.